# Корректировка анимации в Google Chrome

Tags: jquery

Задача перед мной стояла такая, скрыть 3 первых столбца в таблице, в итоге скрыл. Но отображение в Chrome странное, как только открываю страницу с таблицей примерно на 1 секунды появляются первые 3 столбца которые я скрыл, и как только 1 секунда проходит столбцы скрываются. Попробовал открыть в Мозиле там идеально работает, то есть открыл таблицу первых 3 столбцов не видно. Встречаюсь с таким впервые, как можно решить проблему ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
            $('#table td:nth-child(1)').css("display", "none");
            $('#table td:nth-child(2)').css("display", "none");
            ('#$table td:nth-child(3)').css("display", "none");
             });
```

Comment: Это вполне нормально. Сначала загружается код страницы, а потом выполняется сам скрипт скрытия блоков. Почему бы вам не скрыть их в *html*? (`style="display:block"`)

Comment: таблица выводится циклом у меня)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Способ №1:

```css
#table td:nth-child(1), #table td:nth-child(2), #table td:nth-child(3) {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Способ №2:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#table td:nth-child(1)').css("display", "none");
  $('#table td:nth-child(2)').css("display", "none");
  $('#table td:nth-child(3)').css("display", "none");
  $('body').css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
body {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: 2 Способ, идеально решил мою проблему. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Так пока `$(document).ready` не сработал (т.е. не загрузился весь контент и файлы скриптов и стилей), его функция не скрывает эти столбцы. Перенесите display:none в css и он отработает быстрее и мигания не будет.